# SQL Query to return count of rows meeting a condition for each row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 2 columns A and B where A is an ID and B is some value, lets say

```
A  B
1  India
2  USA
3  India
4  Canada
```

I am trying to write a Query to returns results so that for each unique value in B, it will return the number of rows having that value.

So the output will be

```
India 2
USA   1
Canada 1
```

Comment: Take a look at `GROUP BY` clause in the documentation to start with.

Comment: This is a very basic aggregation query using `group by`.  You should study the basics of the SQL language.

Answer (score 6):

Just use a `GROUP BY`

```
  SELECT B, 
         COUNT(*)
    FROM mytable
GROUP BY B
```

Answer (score 0):

For unique values you should use `Distinct` and for counting you can use `Count(*)`

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) 
FROM table_name;
```